# How do i find Fibonacci numbers in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

```
(define (fib n)
  (fib-iter 1 0 n))
(define (fib-iter a b count)
  (if (= count 0)
    b
    (fib-iter (+ a b) a (- count 1))))
```

Just having some fun with SICP.
I completely understand the idea of Fibonacci algorithm but this code made me stuck up.
What exactly the last line does in compare to imperative style thing(is this just a basic recursion or)?

Comment: This is a classic example of recursion.  Do you understand recursion?

Comment: Yes. I think i need about syntax, in this situation. a + b should be at the first argument, (a + b) + a) the second argument, and the result + ( count - 1) as a third argument. But this is incorrect, i guess.

Comment: @ReutSharabani actually no, this is not the classic recursive implementation of the Fibonacci series, this is an _iterative_ process implementation.

Comment: That's interesting. I thought this is a recursive process. With a tail call. Is that not the case?

Comment: @ReutSharabani syntactically is a recursion, but the process it generates is iterative, because as you clearly stated, it's using a tail call.

Comment: As long as we're on the same page (or in the same frame, for that matter)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is implementing the Fibonacci series as an *iterative* process. In this case, `fib` is the main procedure that calls `fib-iter`, which does the actual work by means of an iteration. Notice that `count` is used to control the number of iterations we want, whereas `a` and `b` are used to store the results of the Fibonacci series for `n-1` and `n-2` respectively. The line `(fib-iter (+ a b) a (- count 1))` is advancing the iteration to the next values.

Please take the time to read about iterative vs. recursive processes in the book, also read about tail recursion - these are the concepts you need to grasp for really understanding what's happening in the example.

For comparison, let's see how the same procedures would look using a more conventional syntax (Python's):

```
def fib(n):
  return fib_iter(1, 0, n)

def fib_iter(a, b, count):
  while count != 0:  # same as asking `(if (= count 0) ...)`
    a, b = a + b, a  # same as passing `(+ a b) a` to recursive call
    count -= 1       # same as `(- count 1)`
  return b           # same as returning `b` at end of recursion
```

As you see, the `fib_iter` procedure is simply iterating over a range of values controlled by the `count` variable, assigning `a` and `b` to the next values in the series, up until a number of iterations is completed; at this point the result is in `b` and is returned.

Comment: What exactly the first iteration returns? and the second one?

Comment: @Caleb I wrote the same code in a more familiar syntax, is this clearer now?

Comment: Please, correct me if i'm wrong:
The last line of the Scheme code would be something like this:
- FIrst iteration 1 1 4,
- Second iteration 2 1 3,
- Third iteration  3 2 2,
- Fifth iteration  5 3 1.
Is this correct?

Comment: Oh, i just didn't put the 1 0 5 as a first iteration but if i did, i'm still wrong?
If we take 5 as a base for our algorithm here.
`(1 0 5) (1 1 4) (2 1 3) (3 2 2 ) ( 5 3 1 )`

Comment: You're right, the iterations for `n=5` will look like this: `(1 0 5) (1 1 4) (2 1 3) (3 2 2) (5 3 1)`

Comment: Alright, i got it.! My problem was that i messed up with the Syntax of Scheme. Your explanation is great, thank you.